How to install install Msys2 package icu package for ruby gem?
I am trying to install the Ruby gem github-linguist. I am on a Windows machine, and I have tried executing gem install github-linguist via the Msys2, Mingw64, and the regular Windows command shell. I get the same output every time:
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing github-linguist:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: C:/ghcup/msys64/mingw64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/charlock_holmes-0.7.9/ext/charlock_holmes
C:/ghcup/msys64/mingw64/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for pkg-config for icu-i18n... not found
checking for pkg-config for icu-io... not found
checking for pkg-config for icu-uc... not found
checking for -licui18n... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --without-opt-include
        --with-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --without-opt-lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/ghcup/msys64/mingw64/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
        --with-icu-dir
        --without-icu-dir
        --with-icu-include=${icu-dir}/include
        --without-icu-include
        --with-icu-lib=${icu-dir}/lib
        --without-icu-lib
        --with-icu-i18n-dir
        --without-icu-i18n-dir
        --with-icu-i18n-include=${icu-i18n-dir}/include
        --without-icu-i18n-include
        --with-icu-i18n-lib=${icu-i18n-dir}/lib
        --without-icu-i18n-lib
        --with-icu-i18n-config
        --without-icu-i18n-config
        --with-pkg-config
        --without-pkg-config
        --with-icu-io-dir
        --without-icu-io-dir
        --with-icu-io-include=${icu-io-dir}/include
        --without-icu-io-include
        --with-icu-io-lib=${icu-io-dir}/lib
        --without-icu-io-lib
        --with-icu-io-config
        --without-icu-io-config
        --with-icu-uc-dir
        --without-icu-uc-dir
        --with-icu-uc-include=${icu-uc-dir}/include
        --without-icu-uc-include
        --with-icu-uc-lib=${icu-uc-dir}/lib
        --without-icu-uc-lib
        --with-icu-uc-config
        --without-icu-uc-config
        --with-icui18n-dir
        --without-icui18n-dir
        --with-icui18n-include=${icui18n-dir}/include
        --without-icui18n-include
        --with-icui18n-lib=${icui18n-dir}/lib
        --without-icui18n-lib
        --with-icui18nlib
        --without-icui18nlib
C:/ghcup/msys64/mingw64/lib/ruby/3.3.0/mkmf.rb:480:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.

        from C:/ghcup/msys64/mingw64/lib/ruby/3.3.0/mkmf.rb:573:in `try_link0'
        from C:/ghcup/msys64/mingw64/lib/ruby/3.3.0/mkmf.rb:591:in `try_link'
        from C:/ghcup/msys64/mingw64/lib/ruby/3.3.0/mkmf.rb:809:in `try_func'
        from C:/ghcup/msys64/mingw64/lib/ruby/3.3.0/mkmf.rb:1056:in `block in have_library'
        from C:/ghcup/msys64/mingw64/lib/ruby/3.3.0/mkmf.rb:983:in `block in checking_for'
        from C:/ghcup/msys64/mingw64/lib/ruby/3.3.0/mkmf.rb:344:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
        from C:/ghcup/msys64/mingw64/lib/ruby/3.3.0/mkmf.rb:314:in `open'
        from C:/ghcup/msys64/mingw64/lib/ruby/3.3.0/mkmf.rb:344:in `block in postpone'
        from C:/ghcup/msys64/mingw64/lib/ruby/3.3.0/mkmf.rb:314:in `open'
        from C:/ghcup/msys64/mingw64/lib/ruby/3.3.0/mkmf.rb:340:in `postpone'
        from C:/ghcup/msys64/mingw64/lib/ruby/3.3.0/mkmf.rb:982:in `checking_for'
        from C:/ghcup/msys64/mingw64/lib/ruby/3.3.0/mkmf.rb:1051:in `have_library'
        from extconf.rb:37:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  C:/ghcup/msys64/mingw64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/3.3.0/charlock_holmes-0.7.9/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/ghcup/msys64/mingw64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/charlock_holmes-0.7.9 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/ghcup/msys64/mingw64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/3.3.0/charlock_holmes-0.7.9/gem_make.ou

The mkmf.log file mentioned in the error message says this:
pkg_config: checking for pkg-config for icu-i18n... -------------------- not found

PATH=".;C:/ghcup/msys64/mingw64/lib;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Elm\0.19.1\bin;C:\Users\dawie\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\dawie\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\dawie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\;C:\Users\dawie\AppData\Local\Programs\R\R-4.4.1\bin\;C:\Users\dawie\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\cmd;C:\ghcup\bin;C:\Users\dawie\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\ghcup\msys64\usr\bin;C:\ghcup\msys64\mingw64\bin;" pkg-config --exists icu-i18n
package configuration for icu-i18n is not found
--------------------

pkg_config: checking for pkg-config for icu-io... -------------------- not found

PATH=".;C:/ghcup/msys64/mingw64/lib;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Elm\0.19.1\bin;C:\Users\dawie\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\dawie\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\dawie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\;C:\Users\dawie\AppData\Local\Programs\R\R-4.4.1\bin\;C:\Users\dawie\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\cmd;C:\ghcup\bin;C:\Users\dawie\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\ghcup\msys64\usr\bin;C:\ghcup\msys64\mingw64\bin;" pkg-config --exists icu-io
package configuration for icu-io is not found
--------------------

pkg_config: checking for pkg-config for icu-uc... -------------------- not found

PATH=".;C:/ghcup/msys64/mingw64/lib;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Elm\0.19.1\bin;C:\Users\dawie\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\dawie\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\dawie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\;C:\Users\dawie\AppData\Local\Programs\R\R-4.4.1\bin\;C:\Users\dawie\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\cmd;C:\ghcup\bin;C:\Users\dawie\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\ghcup\msys64\usr\bin;C:\ghcup\msys64\mingw64\bin;" pkg-config --exists icu-uc
package configuration for icu-uc is not found
--------------------

PATH=".;C:/ghcup/msys64/mingw64/lib;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Elm\0.19.1\bin;C:\Users\dawie\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\dawie\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\dawie\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\;C:\Users\dawie\AppData\Local\Programs\R\R-4.4.1\bin\;C:\Users\dawie\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\cmd;C:\ghcup\bin;C:\Users\dawie\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\ghcup\msys64\usr\bin;C:\ghcup\msys64\mingw64\bin;" "gcc -o conftest.exe -IC:/ghcup/msys64/mingw64/include/ruby-3.3.0/x64-mingw32 -IC:/ghcup/msys64/mingw64/include/ruby-3.3.0/ruby/backward -IC:/ghcup/msys64/mingw64/include/ruby-3.3.0 -I. -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -march=nocona -msahf -mtune=generic -O2 -pipe -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wp,-D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO=1 -Wno-incompatible-pointer-types conftest.c  -L. -LC:/ghcup/msys64/mingw64/lib -L. -fstack-protector-strong -Wl,--no-as-needed     -lx64-msvcrt-ruby330  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi -lbcrypt  "
In file included from C:/ghcup/msys64/mingw64/include/ruby-3.3.0/ruby/internal/config.h:22,
                 from C:/ghcup/msys64/mingw64/include/ruby-3.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:15,
                 from C:/ghcup/msys64/mingw64/include/ruby-3.3.0/ruby.h:38,
                 from conftest.c:1:
C:/ghcup/msys64/mingw64/include/ruby-3.3.0/x64-mingw32/ruby/config.h:217:15: error: two or more data types in declaration specifiers
  217 | #define uid_t int
      |               ^~~
C:/ghcup/msys64/mingw64/include/ruby-3.3.0/x64-mingw32/ruby/config.h:218:15: error: two or more data types in declaration specifiers
  218 | #define gid_t int
      |               ^~~
In file included from C:/ghcup/msys64/mingw64/include/ruby-3.3.0/ruby/internal/value.h:23,
                 from C:/ghcup/msys64/mingw64/include/ruby-3.3.0/ruby/internal/intern/class.h:24,
                 from C:/ghcup/msys64/mingw64/include/ruby-3.3.0/ruby/internal/anyargs.h:76,
                 from C:/ghcup/msys64/mingw64/include/ruby-3.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:27:
C:/ghcup/msys64/mingw64/include/ruby-3.3.0/ruby/internal/static_assert.h:51:46: error: static assertion failed: "sizeof_long: SIZEOF_LONG == sizeof(long)"
   51 | # define RBIMPL_STATIC_ASSERT0 __extension__ _Static_assert
      |                                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:/ghcup/msys64/mingw64/include/ruby-3.3.0/ruby/internal/static_assert.h:70:5: note: in expansion of macro ΓÇÿRBIMPL_STATIC_ASSERT0ΓÇÖ
   70 |     RBIMPL_STATIC_ASSERT0(expr, # name ": " # expr)
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:/ghcup/msys64/mingw64/include/ruby-3.3.0/ruby/internal/value.h:129:1: note: in expansion of macro ΓÇÿRBIMPL_STATIC_ASSERTΓÇÖ
  129 | RBIMPL_STATIC_ASSERT(sizeof_long, SIZEOF_LONG == sizeof(long));
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/w32api/winsock2.h:56,
                 from conftest.c:3:
/usr/include/w32api/psdk_inc/_fd_types.h:100:2: warning: #warning "fd_set and associated macros have been defined in sys/types.      This can cause runtime problems with W32 sockets" [-Wcpp]
  100 | #warning "fd_set and associated macros have been defined in sys/types.  \
      |  ^~~~~~~
/usr/include/w32api/winsock2.h:1031:34: error: conflicting types for ΓÇÿselectΓÇÖ; have ΓÇÿint(int,  fd_set *, fd_set *, fd_set *, const TIMEVAL *)ΓÇÖ
 1031 |   WINSOCK_API_LINKAGE int WSAAPI select(int nfds,fd_set *readfds,fd_set *writefds,fd_set *exceptfds,const TIMEVAL *timeout);
      |                                  ^~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/sys/types.h:50,
                 from C:/ghcup/msys64/mingw64/include/ruby-3.3.0/ruby/defines.h:19,
                 from C:/ghcup/msys64/mingw64/include/ruby-3.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:25:
/usr/include/sys/select.h:80:5: note: previous declaration of ΓÇÿselectΓÇÖ with type ΓÇÿint(int,  fd_set *, fd_set *, fd_set *, struct timeval *)ΓÇÖ
   80 | int select __P ((int __n, fd_set *__readfds, fd_set *__writefds,
      |     ^~~~~~
/usr/include/w32api/winsock2.h:1040:34: error: conflicting types for ΓÇÿgethostnameΓÇÖ; have ΓÇÿint(char *, int)ΓÇÖ
 1040 |   WINSOCK_API_LINKAGE int WSAAPI gethostname(char *name,int namelen);
      |                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/ssp/stdio.h:34,
                 from /usr/include/stdio.h:804,
                 from C:/ghcup/msys64/mingw64/include/ruby-3.3.0/ruby/defines.h:16:
/usr/include/ssp/unistd.h:60:1: note: previous definition of ΓÇÿgethostnameΓÇÖ with type ΓÇÿint(char *, size_t)ΓÇÖ {aka ΓÇÿint(char *, long unsigned int)ΓÇÖ}
   60 | __ssp_redirect(int, gethostname, (char *__buf, size_t __len), \
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2:
3: #include <winsock2.h>
4: #include <windows.h>
5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
6: {
7:   return !!argv[argc];
8: }
/* end */

The problem appears to be an issue with the -licui18n library, so I tried installing that package with pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-icu in the Msys2 shell, and it works perfectly with no errors. But then when I run gem install github-linguist again it still doesn't work. I'm not sure what the error message means by "you must install development tools first", that's not very specific.
I'm not very familiar with Makefile, so the error message may be more intelligible to someone who has more experience with it.

I expect you need to install package icu-devel (too).

I installed that, and ran gem install again, and got the same message. I also tried restarting the command shell. I also tried installing icu-devel and the gem from the Mingw shell as well.

Solved! I needed to point the installer to where the icu lib files were. I had installed the package multiple times in my various attempts to solve the problem, and therefore had installed the .dll files to both the /mingw64/lib/ and /usr/lib/ directories. I ran the following command in the Mingw64 shell: find /usr -name 'libicu*' and saw this:
/usr/lib/libicudata75.dll.a
/usr/lib/libicui18n.dll.a
/usr/lib/libicui18n75.dll.a
/usr/lib/libicuio.dll.a
/usr/lib/libicuio75.dll.a
/usr/lib/libicutest.dll.a
/usr/lib/libicutest75.dll.a
/usr/lib/libicutu.dll.a
/usr/lib/libicutu75.dll.a
/usr/lib/libicuuc.dll.a
/usr/lib/libicuuc75.dll.a
/usr/lib/w32api/libicu.a

Notice the presence of the libicui18n.dll.a file. That is the one the installer needed. Then I ran gem install github-linguist -- --with-icu-lib=/usr/lib and it worked!
